# Mismatch in formal parameter list while compiling template function

Tags: c++, template-specialization, function-templates

I'm getting compile time error while compiling templated function, the error is:

> error C2563 : mismatch in formal parameter list

Can't figure out where the problem is, compiler doesn't tell much, do you see what the problem could be?

```
#include <cmath>    // temporary
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

namespace math
{
    //
    // Power function
    //
    template<typename Exp>
    double pow(double base, Exp exponent)
    {
        assert(!(base == 0 && exp <= 0));

        if (base == 0)
            return 0;

        if (exponent == 0 || base == 1)
            return 1;

        if (exponent == 1)
            return base;

        if (exponent < 0)
            return 1 / pow(base, -exponent);

        return base * pow(base, exponent - 1);
    }

    //
    // Power specialization for real exponents
    //
    template<>
    double pow(double base, double exponent)
    {
        // TODO: handle real negative exponents
        return exp(exponent * log(base));
    }
}

int main()
{
    // error C2563:  mismatch in formal parameter list
    std::cout << "pow" << std::endl;
    std::cout << math::pow(1, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << math::pow(0, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << math::pow(2, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << math::pow(3, -4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `exp` in the assertion?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/ you compare 0 to a function

Comment: @lubgr I see that should be `exponent` I renamed the parameters but forgot that, isn't compiler supposed to report undeclared identifier heh?

Comment: If you compile with clang, it shows a bit more information
https://godbolt.org/z/Nunybv

Comment: Well, there is an `exp` function that some compilers offer in addition to that declared in `std`.

Comment: Error from clang: *"main.cpp:13:35: error: ordered comparison between pointer and zero ('double (*)(double) throw()' and 'int')"*

Comment: @zebanovich Templates are not consumable goods, they are factories that make goods. A class template is not a class. Templates cannot be checked like regular stuff, only limited checking is done before instanciation. Undeclared identifiers *should* be detected *but* a type mismatch can be checked later.

Comment: `NDEBUG` was not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though I should write an answer for others to see.

In the comment written by Martin Morterol he explains why you get the error.

You are comparing exp function with 0. 
`assert(!(base == 0 && exp <= 0));`

I assume you want to assert against negative exponents so I've replaced
exp with exponent and it outputted the right data according to the assumption.

Exp is a function available in the cmath header which returns the base-e exponential function of x, which is e raised to the power x: ex.

As to why GCC compiles, it seems like it completely ignores the assert line as can be seen on godbolt if we look in assembly

https://godbolt.org/z/BZIw8z

If we replace assert with static_assert, gcc gives us the same error as clang

https://godbolt.org/z/UpQ6Ks